# Getting error when adding another function

Tags: java, android

When I am running Price method I am getting an IllegealStateException but when I just run it with display method I don't get any error

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int number = 2;
    display(number);
   Price(2* 5);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given price on the screen.
 */
private void Price(int number) {
    TextView priceEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
    priceEditText.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void Price(int number) {
    TextView priceEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
    priceEditText.setText(number.toSting());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code like below.

```
private void Price(int number) {
    TextView priceEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
    priceEditText.setText(String.valueOf(number));
}
```